# Не хочет импортироваться модуль random в cx_Freeze

Tags: python

Решил недавно скоимпилировать .py программу в исполняемый файл, и столкнулся с одной проблемой. Сначала скомпилированная прога просто не запускалась, затем я через каждую строчку понавтыкал input() и оказалось что программа падает именно при попытке импортирования модуля random.

P.S. python 3.2

Comment: А как вы его импортируете?

Comment: import random  
дык када я тестю программку еще в формате .ру то она прекрасно работает

Comment: Вы пробовали добавить этот модуль в список модулей импортируемых с вашим приложением?

Как я вам показывал в предыдущем вопросе

Comment: в этом проекте нет setup.py тут чисто два файла , один это графический интерфейс сделанный при помощи qt designer и второй собсно сама программка, а если я пишу туда то что вы мне написали то она даже в формате .ру не заускается. самое интересное я даже взял и тупо закинул все содержимое random.py в это дело, хотя в формате .ру она запускалась а скомпилированная нет!

Comment: Ну а как вы компилируете?

Из коммандной строки? В мануал заглядывали? Там есть ключ `--include-modules`, а дальше через запятую после пробела необходимые модули.

Comment: спасибо разобрался я создал setup.py а затем через консоль запускал прогу, она писала что не хватает модулей я их туда накидал терь все хоршо! у меня только один вопрос остался. моя программа с графическим интерфейсом и почему то она уже скомпилированная открывается вместе с консолью, что нужно написать в setup.py чтобы она открывалась без консоли?

Comment: @Вова Сысков, создайте отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы с использованием `cxfreeze` и модуля `random` нет. По крайней мере на современных версиях:

```bsh
$ cxfreeze --version  # pip install cx_Freeze -U
cxfreeze 5.1.1
```

Чтобы убедиться, можно попробовать собрать программу, которая бросание костей реализует:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random

print(*[random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(2)])  # roll the dice
```

Пример запуска:

```bsh
$ python3 .
2 5
```

Чтобы получить: `dist/roll-the-dice` исполняемый файл:

```bsh
$ cxfreeze --target-name=rool-the-dice __main__.py
```

Чтобы убедиться, что системный python не используется, можно в docker контейнере запустить. Проверяем, что нет python3 команды:

```bsh
$ docker run --rm ubuntu:16.04 python3 -V         
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348
: starting container process caused "exec: \"python3\": executable file not found in 
$PATH": unknown.
```

Запускаем команду:

```bsh
$ docker run --rm -v $PWD/dist:/work ubuntu:16.04 /work/roll-the-dice
1 2
```

Таким образом убедились, что `/dist` директория всё необходимое для запуска содержит:

```bsh
$ ls dist
lib roll-the-dice
$ tree dist | grep random
│   ├── _random.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
$ tree -d dist
dist
└── lib
    ├── collections
    ├── email
    │   └── mime
    ├── encodings
    ├── html
    ├── http
    ├── importlib
    ├── logging
    ├── pydoc_data
    ├── unittest
    │   └── test
    │       └── testmock
    ├── urllib
    └── xml
        ├── dom
        ├── etree
        ├── parsers
        └── sax

19 directories
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
y = randint(1,3)
код = -1
print(' ----------------------------------------------------------')
print('|            Вгадай код, щоб пройти далі...                |')          
print('|              (Це число від 1 до 4):                      |')
print(' ----------------------------------------------------------')
print(' ')
while код != y:
    код = int(input('    Твій варіант:'))
    if код != y:
        print('|                                                          |')
        print('|             Ні, код хибний.                              |')
        print('|                            Спробуй ще!                   |')
        print('|__________________________________________________________|')
        print('')
    else:
        print('|                                                          |')
        print('|             Вітаю, код вірний!                           |')
        print('|                                                          |')
        print('|                            ЗАХОДЬ ;)                     |')
        print('|                                                          |')
        print(' ----------------------------------------------------------')
```

Comment: попробуй так у меня работает! )

Comment: расскажите, пожалуйста, как ваш код поможет решить оригинальную проблему?

Comment: ну человек говорит, что у него не запускается random, я показал как у меня запускается!!!

Comment: pip3 install pyinstaller